# Algorithm for merging two sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Just wondering if the following solution is good.
I checked and it seems correct, although ostensibly quite different from the traditional "two pointers" solution.

The idea is to iterate both arrays simultaneously running maxSize iterations where maxSize is the size of the larger array.

In each iteration, as long as "i < a.Length && i < b.Length", I compare two numbers whose indices in their respective arrays are identical, each time keeping the larger one in the variable prevMax.
Then I compare this prevMax to the new currMax and currMin, and act accordingly.

Now if the iteration exceeds the size of the smaller array, a similar comparison is done only this time between the current number in the larger array and the previous number that was found to be larger, i.e. currMax (problematic variable name I know, I got another version that's more readable, I might post it later) **Definitely not the most elegant solution but I'd like to focus on whether is works or not**.

Here is the code:

```
// example input

int[] b = {-3, -1, 3, 4, 8};
int[] a = {-5, 2, 5, 10, 18};

// defining variables
int prevMax = default, currMax = default, currMin = default;
int maxSize = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);

List<int> result = new List<int>();

// start of algorithm

for(int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
{
    if(i < a.Length && i < b.Length)
    {
        currMax = Math.Max(a[i], b[i]);
        currMin = Math.Min(a[i], b[i]);
    }
    else if(a.Length < b.Length)
    {
        currMin = Math.Min(currMax, b[i]);
        currMax = Math.Max(currMax, b[i]);  
        prevMax = currMax;
    }   
    else if(a.Length > b.Length)
    {
        currMin = Math.Min(currMax, a[i]);
        currMax = Math.Max(currMax, a[i]);      
        prevMax = currMax;
    }

    if(prevMax != currMax && prevMax < currMin)
    {
        result.Add(prevMax);
        result.Add(currMin);        
    }
    else if(prevMax != currMax && prevMax < currMax)
    {   
        result.Add(currMin);
        result.Add(prevMax);
    }
    else result.Add(currMin);

    prevMax = currMax;
}

result.Add(currMax);

// end of algorithm
```

Comment: Try running your code on {1,2,3} and {4,5,6}. Although, if the code is not working, you should test it yourself to find issues, and if the code is working, this might potentially be a [codereview.se]. Neither situation is particularly well-suited for [so].

Comment: I won't review your code, but  this general approach can work. The question is why you'd want to use a pattern that's both more complicated and slower (measured by number of comparisons) than necessary. The better pattern is to merge until one array is consumed. Then copy the remaining chunk of the other array.